# Dúvida com projeto Asp.Net

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Boa tarde pessoal, estou aprendendo ASP.NET e o rapaz que esta ensinando online, começou assim: File, New Web Site e selecionou a opção ASP.NET Web Application e possui as seguintes pastas Account, App_Data... etc... No meu visual studio não tem essa opção só ASP.NET Empty Web Site... Gostaria de saber se tem problema usar essa opção ou terei problemas depois.

Desde já eu agradeço...

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar um print da sua tela?

Comment: Se for problema de instalação do VS, considere usar o VS 2015, mesmo que seja a versão Community que é completa e gratuita.

Comment: Baixei o Visual Studio 2015 e também não tem essa opção.

Answer (score 0):

Não tem problema não. Aquelas pastas são para usuários que sabem muito de ASP e querem organizar melhor o projeto. Mas como você só está começando, acho que não precisa.